# Starling for IOS - Can't load files packaged in ipa when packaging for app store

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, mobile, air, starling-framework

I have an app for iphone created that I created using Starling.

At runtime, from my main SWF, I'm loading external SWFs which were packaged in the ipa.

Whenever I package the app for testing / debuging, it works great, the SWFs are loaded with no problems.

However, whenever I package it for App Store, suddenly trying to load external SWFs results in an error.

I compared the contents of the testing / debugging and app store ipas (opened as zips), both contain the external SWFs I'm trying to load in the exact same path.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error was thrown on IOS because the SWFs contained code, which is unacceptable according to IOS' policy.